# Updating a value of a td without the need to reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I change the status of some patients using AJAX I need to change the value that is displayed by a `<td>` directly to the same value selected from drop list:

```
$(document).on('change', '#patient_status ', function()
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status of a patient ?"))
    {
        var pid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); 
        var new_status = $("#patient_status").val();
        $(this).closest('tr').find('#change_status').val(new_status);
        //console.log(pid + " " + new_status);
        $.ajax({
            url: '../php/changeStatus.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'TEXT',
            data: {pid: pid, new_status: new_status},
            beforeSend:function(){ 
                $('#wait').show(); 
            },
            success:function(resp){

            },
            error:function(resp){

            },
            complete:function()
            {
                $('#wait').hide(); 
            }
        })
    }
});
```

An example is presented by the following image where I changed the status of a patient from active to defaulter, the value changed in database but on screen I need to reload the page.

I think the error is in this line:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('#change_status').val(new_status);
```

The html form is here:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $patient['patient_id']; ?>">
<td id="change_status"><?php echo $patient['patient_status']; ?></td>
<tr>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same `id`? The fact you're doing DOM traversal would indicate that you do, in which case that's the issue. Change them to classes.

Comment: no I don't have any similar id. Can you explain more ?

Comment: I changed them to . instead of # and change the id= into class= but still the same

Comment: Well if the ajax is posting and sending to php then you should have the php return the changes (confirm) and use the success event handler as that will only trigger if the ajax call is a success.... which appear to be empty in your source code. For more information please read the jQuery ajax documents. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: fixed now the problem is it only change the first row of the table and the other rows cannot be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ajax success you can do like this :

```
success:function(resp){
$('#td _id').html(change_status_value);// just a demo 
            },
```

Comment: fixed now the problem is it only change the first row of the table and the other rows cannot be changed

Comment: its expected . But if you want to change all rows at same time then your #td_id should be same for all rows

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use class instead of id for multiple elements.
 
eg: `<td class="change_status">` 

Secondly use
**`$(this).html(new_status);`**
Instead of 
**`$(this).closest('tr').find('#change_status').val(new_status);`**