# The first row of an HTML table is being updated by Ajax and the other rows are taking the default value on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am updating the status of a user as in [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824835/updating-a-value-of-a-td-without-the-need-to-reload-the-page?noredirect=1).

My Problem is now that only the first row of the table is changed normally and whatever the value of the drop list of the rows, the value displayed and sent is now `select`.

Here is my Ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(document).on('change', '#patient_status ', function()
{
    var pid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    var current_status = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.change_status').text();
    var new_status = $("#patient_status").val();
    if(current_status == new_status)
    {
        alert("The status selected is already the same!");
    }
    else
    {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status of a patient ?"))
        {

            $(this).closest('tr').children('td.change_status').text(new_status);
            //console.log(pid + " " + new_status);
            $.ajax({
                url: '../php/changeStatus.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'TEXT',
                data: {pid: pid, new_status: new_status},
                success:function(resp){

                },
                error:function(resp){

                },
            })
        }
    }
});
});
```

And here my HTML table:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $patient['patient_id']; ?>">
<td id="change_status"><?php echo $patient['patient_status']; ?></td>
<tr>
<td>
  <select style="color: #0090ff; " class="form-control select" name="patient_status" id="patient_status">
  <option value="select">Select</option>
  <option value="Active">Active</option>
  <option value="Deceased">Deceased</option>
  <option value="Discharged">Discharged</option>
  <option value="Defaulter">Defaulter</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

The result is like the following:

[image]

The first row is changed normally to Active as the drop list indicates.

The second row the value was discharged, and the value in database and on the screen was changed to `select`.

**I think the problem is in here:**

```
var new_status = $("#patient_status").val();
```

**or the on change event is not the case to use here.**

**EDIT**

Whatever the value selected in the second row and afterwards I console it and it was just: `select` as the value displayed.

I changed the line that I am suspecting into:

```
var new_status = $("#patient_status option:selected").text();
```

But nothing changed at all.

Comment: pid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');   that get a undefined

Comment: try to use x-editable edit `https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/`

Comment: @noni yes but not for the first row

Comment: try this  var pid = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id'); , `prop` instead of `attr`. Some time `attr` return undenfined , but `prop` give you right value

Comment: None of your references to `$("td.change_status")` will find anything. You have no `td` with that class, although you do have an `id` of "change_status", in which case `$("#change_status")` would do better. Also, given that your `select` and the `td#change_status` are in different rows, even `$(this).closest('tr').children('#change_status')` wouldn't find anything.

Comment: @PaulRoub can you type an answer ?

Comment: Exactly when the ajax call return it would be like . data: {pid: pid, new_status: new_status},pid = undefined, new_status = "Active"

Comment: but is defined for the first row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given every select the same id, but an id has to be unique.

I suggest giving the select a class `patient_status` instead and changing the JS accordingly.

So something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.patient_status', function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    var $tr = $select.closest('tr');
    var pid = $tr.attr('id');
    var $status = $tr.children('td.change_status');
    var current_status = $status.text();
    var new_status = $select.val();
    if (current_status == new_status) {
      alert("The status selected is already the same!");
    }
    else {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change the status of a patient ?")) {
        $status.text(new_status);
        //console.log(pid + " " + new_status);
        $.ajax({
          url: '../php/changeStatus.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'TEXT',
          data: { pid: pid, new_status: new_status },
          success: function(resp) {},
          error: function(resp) {}
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

There's also an issue with an open tr tag somewhere in the middle of your html and a reference to `td.change_status`, but this element and class combination doesn't exist in your html. There is a td with an id of `change_status` but then you have the same problem as stated above in that it is not unique.

**Edit: HTML fix below**

```
<tr id="<?php echo $patient['patient_id']; ?>">
  <td class="change_status"><?php echo $patient['patient_status']; ?></td>
  <td>
    <select style="color: #0090ff; " class="form-control select patient_status" name="patient_status">
      <option value="select">Select</option>
      <option value="Active">Active</option>
      <option value="Deceased">Deceased</option>
      <option value="Discharged">Discharged</option>
      <option value="Defaulter">Defaulter</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```